# Android showing Image in Gallery which needs to be downloaded from Internet

Tags: android, gallery, android-asynctask

I am writing an application in which I need to show images from the URLs. Now suppose I have to show 100 images, one after the another and each photo needs to be downloaded from the internet.

I am using the Gallery View to show the images, but the problem is when I pass the URL to `getView` function it starts downloading all the 100 images (yes in Async Task only), but downloading 100 images slows down the system. What I want to achieve is, when i move right, my program should pick the url and download it from the internet.

```
public class ViewImage extends Activity {

private String albumID;
private ArrayList<MediaBO>galleryList;
private Context context;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.localgallery);

    this.context = this;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    albumID = extras.getString("albumID");
    int position = extras.getInt("position"); //position of the image selected

    DataBaseOperation dataBaseOperation = new DataBaseOperation(this);
    galleryList = dataBaseOperation.queryAllPhoto(albumID); //this returns the list of Photos needs to be shown.it has the URL of the photos

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.localGallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    g.setSelection(position);

}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return galleryList.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.localgallery, null);
        }
        String url = galleryList.get(position).getUrl();

        DOWNLOAD()//download the photo using Async Task
        v = i;
        return v;
    }

}
   }
```

Now the problem here is `getview` is called as soon as the activity is loaded for all the URL present in the `GalleyList` which slows down the system

---

@cyngus: i was trying to use your answer.. but now sure how to use this..

I created the executor object as suggested by you

```
    Executor e = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAX_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

But i m not able to find out how to use this for calling my Async Task(BitmapDownloaderTask)

```
    BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(con,showDialog,i,path);
    task.execute(url,null,null);
```

My Asyn Task is

```
    private class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    }
```

Comment: follow this url here downloading images from internet and add it to gridview using progress bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415804/android-progress-not-working-accordingly/13416436#comment18333882_13416436

Answer (score 0):

The default `Executor` for AsyncTask is a `ThreadPoolExecutor` that uses a `LinkedBlockingQueue` that is capacity restricted to 10 items. This means that once the queue unhandled queue reaches 10 items, the `Executor` starts adding Threads since it can't add more items to the work queue. If you want to prevent this, you could create your own `Executor`.

```
// same values as the default implementation in AsyncTask
int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 128;
int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

Executor e = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAX_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Then you can call `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()`. This will use an unbounded queue, which is *possibly* not exactly what you want or the best for all possible use cases, but it should keep the number of worker threads at 5 and limit the slowdown you see.

Answer (score 0):

I guess lazy loading can solve your problem. Have a look at the link [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)   This is done for listview in this example but can be implmented with gridview also.