# GridView image gallery onClick example

Tags: android, image, gridview, onclick, android-asynctask

I am new to the Android development so don't mind asking me simple question like this.
I am trying to implement simple gallery from example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html, but I am not sure how to **make clicked thumbnail show in full screen or something like that**.
Also, it would be very nice if someone could explain to me how to, in this case, load images from urls via **AsyncTask**.
Thanks!!

Comment: Try this, It might help you


[Example1(Aysnc Task with loading Images)][1]


[Example2(Image Gallery)][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729133/using-asynctask-to-load-images-in-listview
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561202/android-showing-image-in-gallery-which-needs-to-be-downloaded-from-internet